# Doctrine ORM Manager named "" does not exist - syntax error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I think all parameters are set properly but when I run command of

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --em=archive
```

it throws an error:

> Doctrine ORM Manager named "archive" does not exist.

So I think I might have a syntax problem that I cannot find.

My code:

```
 doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
         default:
             driver: pdo_mysql
             host: '%database_host%'
             port: '%database_port%'
             dbname: '%database_name%'
             user: '%database_user%'
             password: '%database_password%'
             charset: UTF8
         archive:
             driver: pdo_mysql
             host: '%database2_host%'
             port: '%database2_port%'
             dbname: '%database2_name%'
             user: '%database2_user%'
             password: '%database2_password%'
             charset:  UTF8


orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    mappings:
        Default:
            mapping: true
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/App/Base/Entity'
            alias: 'Default'
            prefix: 'Default\Base\Entity'
            is_bundle: false
        Archive:
            mapping: true
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/App/Base/Entity/Archive'
            alias: 'Archive'
            prefix: 'App\Base\Entity\Archive'
            is_bundle: false
```

Also I set parameters.yml correctly, too.

Comment: Is it normal that you capitalize the keys `Default` and `Archive` under `orm`, but have the all lowercase under `dba1`? Your YAML is invalid, but that is probably because you did not indent all lines with 4 spaces (select a block and press Ctrl+K)